# VSCode multiple shells in integrated terminal dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the past I was able to toggle among various shells in the VSCode terminal by selecting them from the terminal's drop down. I'm on a new machine and for some reason no matter what shells I have installed, I only ever see the default shell as an option.

I must be missing something, but searching online hasn't helped. Ex I have node, bash and zsh installed, but this is what the drop down looks like.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown just shows what's running in each open terminal tab.  If you click the `+`, then there will be two tabs, and two items in the list.

If, in Tab 2, you type `zsh` to change the shell, then your dropdown will read `1. Bash; 2. Zsh`.  Same if you open a third and type `node`.

Perhaps your previous configuration opened 3 tabs by default, but in any case, it should be as simple as typing the `node`, `bash`, or `zsh` in the terminal's command line to switch -- provided you have those installed on your new system.

As for which is the VSCode default, you can configure that in the settings GUI or `settings.json`.

-- Edit --
The OP found a solution (quoted from comment):

> `Terminals Manager` does something very similar - opens multiple terminal tabs with different/configurable shells.

Comment: Your answer led me on the right path! It looks like `Terminals Manager` does something very similar - opens multiple terminal tabs with different/configurable shells. Thanks

Comment: @Barryman9000 You're welcome.  Thanks for commenting with your solution.  I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full steps to go back to terminal dropdown list
https://ilpd-ms.blogspot.com/2021/06/vsc-terminal-dropdown-list.html
File>Preferences>Settings
Workplace
In the search, write (terminal>integrated>Tabs:)
Scroll up to the first result which says (Terminal › Integrated › Tabs: Enabled)
Untick the square below
And here you go. You will notice that terminal is back to dropdown menu.

Comment: Or you could just add this to the settings.json: "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false

Answer (score 0):

If you do "Select Default Shell", and change it to what you want, then click on the plus, you should get a new shell option in the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This overwrites the default setting though, so when I re-open VSCode I'm back to only one option in the drop down (the new default)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for shells with paths here, I have found this is automatic when you are opened in the context of a workspace.

Perhaps you have an old workspace you can open or start by adding paths to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

By using terminal profiles you can achieve what you are intending to do - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles.

Example configuration:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "Cmd": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
  },
  "GitBash": {
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "icon": "terminal-bash",
    "icon": "terminal-bash"
  },
  "PowerShell": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    "icon": "terminal-powershell"
  },
},
```